# Merge first array particular key and value into second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array

```
$arr1 = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [customer_id] => 1 [Expire] => 2019-05-14 [paid] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [customer_id] => 2 [Expire] => 2019-06-20 [paid] => 0 ))
```

and

```
$arr2 = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 3943 [customer_id] => 1 [Expire] => 2019-05-14 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 3944 [customer_id] => 1[Expire] => 2019-05-14 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 4713 [customer_id] => 2 [Expire] => 2019-06-20 ) 
)
```

and try to put first array key and value [paid]=>1 or 0 in second array if customer id and expire match like

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 3943 [customer_id] => 1 [Expire] => 2019-05-14 [paid] => 1) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 3944 [customer_id] => 1 [Expire] => 2019-05-14 [paid] => 1) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 4713 [customer_id] => 2 [Expire] => 2019-06-20 [paid] => 0) 
)
```

I try to merge array in php but not get exact what i want. Is there any php function to do it?.

Comment: What happened to the id 3945, customer_id 2? Why isn't that present in the final desired output?

Comment: Can you make the index of the array as the customer_id instead of 0,1,2..etc? It will make things much easier

Comment: customer_id value can't be 0

Comment: It is best to show us what you've tried and say where it goes wrong. @Qirel The offending id was removed by Deepak3301086 five minutes ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop your second array `$arr2`, and find the index of the first array `$arr1` where the column `customer_id` is the same as in the current iteration of `$arr2`. `array_search()` returns that index, which we can then use to fetch the `paid` index of that array. Then we append it to our array `$arr2`, by doing `$a['paid'] = $paid;`.

Since we loop the array *by reference* (the `&` before `$a` in the loop), the changes we make to it, will be applied back to the original array.

```
foreach ($arr2 as &$a) {
    $customerID = $a['customer_id'];      // This customer ID
    $arr1_key = array_search($customerID, array_column($arr1, 'customer_id'));   // Find the index of this customerID in the first array
    $paid = $arr1[$arr1_key]['paid'];     // Find the paid value matching that customer ID
    $a['paid'] = $paid;
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/Meqtu

**Update**
If you need it to match the ID as well as the expiration date, then use `array_filter()` to fetch the array-element within `$arr1` that matches the date and the ID. Using `reset()`, we use the first element in that array.

```
foreach ($arr2 as &$a) {
    // Find the sub-array of $arr1 that matches this array's date and ID
    $arr1_match  = array_filter($arr1, function($v) use ($a) {
        return $v['customer_id'] == $a['customer_id'] && $v['Expire'] == $a['Expire'];
    });
    // Get the first element from the result
    $paid = reset($arr1_match)['paid'];
    // Append the paid-value to this array (done by reference)
    $a['paid'] = $paid;
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/mov6d

Comment: This is, of course, a good solution. Just want to point out you could have done it the other way around: `foreach ($arr1 as` and search through a column of `$arr2`. Why? Because it seems that `$arr1` is the incoming payment information and `$arr2` is an existing list of customers. I also would put `array_column($arr1, 'customer_id')` outside the `foreach` loop. But hey, these are minor details, this is by far the best solution. You get my upvote.

Comment: Hmm, that may very well be. The issue is though that there are multiple instances of each customer ID in the second array, but only one in the first. There's also fewer entries in the first array than the second. Which means it'll be a tad more tricky to get the desired result (meaning you can't use the snippet above an just replace `$arr1` by `$arr2` and vice-versa).  You're probably right about the array-definitions though.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. That forces you to do it this way. It would be better if the arrays, in the question, had proper names, like `$payments`, `$customers`, or `$orders`, that would give you an better idea what you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks, It's work for me. It save second loop time.

Comment: It's only work for customer id match, if date are different then it's not work. Please check https://3v4l.org/TeTpK

Comment: Need to find index of both (customer_id and Expire). then match both index, if matched, then put paid value.

Comment: Use `array_filter()` to get the correct sub-array in `$arr1` then. See the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes things can be done in hard way:)

```
<?php
$arr1 = [
    ['customer_id' => 1, 'Expire' => '2019-05-14', 'paid' => 1],
    ['customer_id' => 2, 'Expire' => '2019-06-20', 'paid' => 0],
];

$arr2 = [
    ['id' => 3943, 'customer_id' => 1, 'Expire' => '2019-05-14'],
    ['id' => 3944, 'customer_id' => 1, 'Expire' => '2019-05-14'],
    ['id' => 3945, 'customer_id' => 2, 'Expire' => '2019-05-14'],
    ['id' => 4713, 'customer_id' => 2, 'Expire' => '2019-06-20'],
];

foreach ($arr2 as &$item2) {
    foreach ($arr1 as $item1) {
        if (
            $item2['customer_id'] === $item1['customer_id']
            && $item2['Expire'] === $item1['Expire']
        ) {
            $item2['paid'] = $item1['paid'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
unset($item2);

var_dump($arr2);
```

Comment: I think that the `===` triple equals 'Identical Operator' is over the top here. The `==` double equals 'Equal Operator' will do. I really wouldn't care if an 'id' was `3943` (integer) or `"3943"` (string), moreso, I would think they are equal and should be seen as such.

Answer (score 1):

This can fix the issue :

```
$arr1 = array(

            ["customer_id"=>1,"Expire"=> "2019-05-14", "paid"=>1],
            ["customer_id"=>2,"Expire"=> "2019-06-20", "paid"=>0]
    );


$arr2 = array(
           ["id"=>3943, "customer_id"=>1,"Expire"=> "2019-05-14"],
           ["id"=>3944,"customer_id"=>2,"Expire"=> "2019-06-20"],
           ["id"=>4713,"customer_id"=>1,"Expire"=> "2019-05-14"]
    );    


$result= array();    

function getRowByCustomerID($id, $array){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if($value['customer_id'] ==$id){
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}    

foreach($arr2 as $subarr){

    $object = getRowByCustomerID($subarr['customer_id'],$arr1 );
    if(!is_null($object)){
        $object['id']=$subarr['id'];
        $result[]= $object;
    }
}    



var_dump($result);
```

the output is similar to what you are looking for :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["customer_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["Expire"]=>
    string(10) "2019-05-14"
    ["paid"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id"]=>
    int(3943)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["customer_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["Expire"]=>
    string(10) "2019-06-20"
    ["paid"]=>
    int(0)
    ["id"]=>
    int(3944)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["customer_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["Expire"]=>
    string(10) "2019-05-14"
    ["paid"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id"]=>
    int(4713)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `$arr2` is not the same as in the question. See the 'paid' keys.

Comment: you're right, i jut update my answer , this will not hurt the result . thank you @KIKOSoftware

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the layout of the first array I think it will be best to first create an intermediate array that keeps a record of all expire dates for every customer.

The following implementation does not require you to use a nested loop.

```
<?php
$arr1 = [
    ['customer_id' => 1, 'Expire' => '2019-05-14', 'paid' => 1],
    ['customer_id' => 2, 'Expire' => '2019-06-20', 'paid' => 0],
];

$arr2 = [
    ['id' => 3943, 'customer_id' => 1, 'Expire' => '2019-05-14'],
    ['id' => 3944, 'customer_id' => 1, 'Expire' => '2019-05-14'],
    ['id' => 3945, 'customer_id' => 2, 'Expire' => '2019-05-14'],
    ['id' => 4713, 'customer_id' => 2, 'Expire' => '2019-06-20'],
];

// Create a list of all paid, expiry dates, keyed by customer_id
$payed = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $item) {
    if (!isset($payed[$item['customer_id']])) {
        $payed[$item['customer_id']] = [];
    }
    $payed[$item['customer_id']][] = $item['Expire'];
}

// Lookup the customer and expire date for every entry
$arr2 = array_map(function($item) use ($payed) { 
    $item['paid'] = in_array($item['Expire'], $payed[$item['customer_id']] ?? []);
    return $item;
}, $arr2);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3943
        [customer_id] => 1
        [Expire] => 2019-05-14
        [paid] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3944
        [customer_id] => 1
        [Expire] => 2019-05-14
        [paid] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3945
        [customer_id] => 2
        [Expire] => 2019-05-14
        [paid] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4713
        [customer_id] => 2
        [Expire] => 2019-06-20
        [paid] => 1
    )

)
```

[See demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94904a997c61c5b5f14a12faed75c3d94e124dee)